# Azure Websites: socket reading port 80 returns 404 error

Tags: sockets, azure, port80

I have a php script that run perfectly when requested by the browser (example):
http://www.kwiksher.com/k3Serial.php?key="XXXXX"

in this case, I get the information of an user with the key XXXXX, which is the expected behavior.

However, inside my Photoshop plugin, I must to call it via socket, having to force a port in the connection:
http://www.kwiksher.com:80/k3Serial.php?key="XXXXX"

Doing that, I get the the content of Azure default 404 page (it is not even my customized 404 page).

If I use the same call (with the port added to the domain) on a browser, it works fine as well.

Any idea on how to fix it? I tried to flushDNS on my machine as well without success.

Thanks a lot,
Alex

Comment: Use fiddle or charles proxy to see what differs between the two requests with the port (photoshop and your browser)

Comment: What are you using in your plugin to manage the socket connection? Sounds like a bug in whatever socket API you are using.  My guess would be the plugin is sending a `Host: www.kwiksher.com:80` header that is confusing `Azure`, whereas the browser is sending a `Host: www.kwiksher.com` header that Azure is handling correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the socket library won't be using HTTP and therefore isn't sending a host header and the web tier on Azure can't actually figure out which Website it should serve the content from.

As you using this with a plug-in perhaps try and use the default hostname issued by Azure instead of a custom domain.